# Nuxt with Axios dont get data from API on page load

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

i'm trying to get data to load in my page with axios in NUXT but nothing appear directly on load i have to delete something in my code and save it for see the data that axios get. On page refresh nothing load too from axios.

here is the code i use in my page :

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
 export default {
  layout: 'women', 
  name: '#app',
  data: {
    results: []
  },
mounted() {
      axios.get("########")
    .then(response => {this.results = response.data.content})
  },
}
</script>



<b-row id="app"  class="wrapper-wm" v-for="result in results" :key="result">
    
        <b-col  sm class="wmgrd"><b-img :src="result.cover"  fluid></b-img></b-col>
         
</b-row>
```

Hope someone can help me find why ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to wait for the response to return in your mounted() method, before the template is rendered. You can use `async/await`.

```
async mounted() {
      await axios.get("########")
    .then(response => {this.results = response.data.content})
  },
}
```

There’s lots of information available for async/await and javascript promises.

As a side note, nuxt provides the `asyncData` method which allows you to grab the data your page needs before it loads.

```
import axios from ‘axios’
export default {
  asyncData() {
    const { data } = await axios.get("########")
    return data
  }
}
```

Now you have access to `data` in your component.

[Nuxt asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data)

Comment: Thank you for your help...it's working great now  :)